# How to handle python i18n translations with react

Tags: reactjs, jinja2

I'm looking into bringing React into my codebase(pyramid, jinja2). It almost looks like a good fit. I'm just confused as to how to handle translations from python. I'm using the `pyramid.i18n` library and I would normally just have `_()` function in context that translates strings like `{{_('Hello')}}` to "Hola" and whatnot. If I moved to React my markup would now be in JS. And I don't want to have Jinja render my JS so it remains static. Is there a good way to handle this?

Comment: I don't think reactjs does that and I'm pretty sure Jinja will not be able to read the virtualdom outputted by React, but I could be wrong, I've never used Jinja.  I think you would need to incorporate a React Translation button that calls some sort of JavaScript language library to translate etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using https://github.com/webpack/i18n-webpack-plugin and serving up the specific bundle file based on a saved language setting.

So on the backend we store in the database which language a user wants to use. We have json files of translations for all the languages & words we support. When compiling the bundle files with this plugin we get a bundle for each language that uses those json files to swap out the translated words. So something like bundle.en.js for english and bundle.es.js for spanish. When a user requests a page we serve up the bundle file associated with their selected language stored in the DB.

Comment: Hey Anthony, I am super interested in your answer, I am facing the same problem. Could you provide me with a bit more explanation on your implem ? How do you make use of the locale negotiated from the back ? How does it integrate with existing locale files generated by msgmerge command ?

Comment: I get the part of rendering, and it seems great, however I am more concerned with the process to use to maintain new translation keys. Can you place translation keys in your js files so that when running a msgmerge, it would add these keys to the pot file ?

Comment: So we actually had a 3rd party company maintain our translations. The key was always the english version and the value would be the translated version. I don't know of anyway to automate that really. But in the actual JS files we used english, something like __('translate me') and then we had a global __() function that would swap those out for the appropriate strings on build.

Comment: Ok I see, so you did not really had to extend what you were doing previously with translation keys in templates but totally replaced it. You are not making use of get-text and pyramid.i18n anymore, right ?

Comment: Correct. This was pretty much a from scratch implementation.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am wondering if someone has an integrative solution with backend internationalization. Do you find any limits in your implementation ?

Comment: Works fine for us. That said our copy doesn't change often so we rarely need to update our translations. So your mileage may vary.